# Javascript api get call returns response but is undefined when chained with .then

Tags: javascript, get

I have the following snippet.  The api call is successful and the api returns the expected data.
However, when I do a console log inside the `.then(payload)` block and log the payload, it is undefined.  Why is this?

```
return API.get.MyData()        
    .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);     // this is valid       
        response.json();        
    })        
    .then(payload => {            
        console.log('payload', payload);  // this is undefined... why???    
    };
```

Comment: You're missing the `return` keyword. A `=>` function whose body is wrapped in `{ }` must explicitly `return` a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `response.json()` to be able to access it in the chained `.then`

Normally, you do something like this:

```js
fetch(...).then(r => r.json()).then(console.log);
```

which implicitly returns `r.json()`, but since you're using `() => { ... }`, you need to explicitly `return`.

```js
return API.get.MyData()        
    .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);     // this is valid       
        return response.json();        
    })        
    .then(payload => {            
        console.log('payload', payload);  // this is undefined... why???    
    };
```